# historical site

Tags: meaning

According to the Cambridge dictionary (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/historic-or-historical), "historic" means "important or likely to be important in history" and "historical" means "related to the study of things from the past". Could I use both adjectives (with different meanings) with the word "site"? Example:

- Machu Picchu is a historic site in Peru. (= MP is important/relevant in history)
- Machu Picchu is a historical site in Peru. (= MP is related to the history of Peru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***[Historic and historical](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=historic%20site%2Chistorical%20site&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chistoric%20site%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chistorical%20site%3B%2Cc0)***  are used in slightly different ways. ***Historic*** means ‘famous or important in history’, as in a historic occasion, whereas ***historical*** means ‘concerning history or historical events’, as in historical evidence; thus a historic event is one that was very important, whereas a historical event is something that happened in the past.

So you can have both [historic and historical sites](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=historic%20site%2Chistorical%20site&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chistoric%20site%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chistorical%20site%3B%2Cc0) depending on the sense that is meant.

[Machu Picchu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machu_Picchu) was declared a ***Peruvian Historic Sanctuary*** in 1981 and a UNESCO World Heritage Site in 1983.

Answer (score -2):

Your definitions are correct.

- Something is only *historic* if it is of historical *importance*. Events, rather than places tend to be described as "historic". For example, *The Battle of Hastings* is *a historic event*.
- Anything which has a history, especially if it is interesting, can be described as "historical". Places in which important historic events took place may also be described as "historical", because they *contain* history. For example, the English town of Hastings, in which The Battle of Hastings took place, is *a historical place*.

Another reason why a place with a history might be better described as "historical" rather than "historic" is that "*historic site*" is a specific term for a place which has been *preserved* for its history - such as a national heritage site. The town of Hastings I used as an example above is still inhabited. However, the castle there is a heritage site, so in isolation may be described as "historic".

In general use though, they are sometimes used interchangeably. More often than not though, they are used as I have described. This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=historic%20place%2C%20historical%20place&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chistoric%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chistorical%20place%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chistoric%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chistorical%20place%3B%2Cc0) shows that places seem to be described as historic *and* historical, but are described as historical almost twice as much.

Lastly, it is worth noting than many English speakers prefer "*an* historic..." over "*a* historic..." (or historical). Others argue that it doesn't really matter these days, and it tends to depend on how people pronounce the word "history" - with a hard, or a softer 'h'.